# Concurrent read access in Entity Framework 4

Tags: entity-framework

Assuming I am never writing with EF, will never call SaveChanges for example, Is EF safe for concurrent reads from the same ObjectContext?

It may still be initialising a database connection and reading new objects, or updating existing objects (or deleting!) but it won't be writing anything to the db, so no transactions (I assume).

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ObjectContext` and related EF classes are not thread safe so don't use them for concurrent operations. If you need to run concurrent data access use a new context for every thread.

Comment: Perfect, I sort of assumed they weren't, but I am forever the optimist :)